# Timer in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, timer

I don't know what's wrong.
The TextView doesn't change it keeps Printing 00.
I expect to get out a simple timer like 0,1,2,....
I want to use threads not classes like timer or timetask.
Thanks for your time.
here's the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView time;
Button start,reset,exit;
Thread aspetta;
int i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tempo);
    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.inizio);
    reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
    exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exit);
    aspetta = new Thread();
    i = 0;

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            waitAMinute(aspetta,time,i);
        }
    });
}
public void waitAMinute(Thread t,TextView tv,int x) {
    x = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            t.sleep(1000);
            tv.setText(Integer.toString(x));
            x++;
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            tv.setText("Error!");
        }
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: I have omitted things like super.onCreate... but these are in my source code.

Comment: You also omitted the fact that Android Studio is IDE and is completely irrelevant what editor you use to write your **java** code for **android**

Comment: You create a thread, but your code isn't actually ran on that thread. On my phone so short answer sorry :-)

Comment: Yes, you are not using any new thread here, you are using the main thread which will make the application freeze.

Comment: There are very few good reasons to use an explicit `Thread` in Android.  The same is true of `Timer`.  For simple delays and timed repetition, the best solution is almost always a `Handler`.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to be creating any threads to accomplish your goal.  It's relatively simple to use a Java Timer() object to set up a repeating callback to your code where you can update the text box.

Exactly what your trying to do here is not 100% clear to me by I'm assuming that you when you click inizio you want the text in the text box to start incrementing such as 1,2,3, etc.  When you hit the reset button you want it to restart from 1 again.  (Note: to make this act like a normal stopwatch you would have the text of the inizio button change to the word 'stop' after the timer is started, etc. )

This code is just to show you the mechanics of using a Timer to set a repeating interval where you can update your UI to show the state of a variable:

```
package com.example.myapp3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    TextView time;
    Button start, reset, exit;
    int i;

    Timer timer = null;
    int tickCount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempo);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inizio);
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);

        i = 0;

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scheduleTimer();
                tickCount = 0;
                time.setText("");
            }
        });

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scheduleTimer();
            }
        });
    }


    public void scheduleTimer() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }

        timer = new Timer();

        TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final TextView myTv = time;
                        myTv.setText(Integer.toString(++tickCount));
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(myTask, 1000, 1000);
    }
}
```